# Switch can not be turned OFF in Flask webapp (only turned ON)

Tags: python, user-interface, flask, request, http-post

I want a switch in my flask webapp to enable/disable the autopilot function of an IoT device.
The switch only seems to work when moving from the OFF to ON position.

If you try to switch it from ON to OFF, it just reloads the page and leaves the switch in the ON position.

### This is the code I use

**In the HTML template** I loop through all the devices to display their Autopilot status with a switch. On click the form gets posted. Here is a simplified piece of the code.

```
  {% for device in devices  %}
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="{{device.unique_id}}.autopilot">Autopilot</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="{{device.unique_id}}.autopilot" {% if device.autopilot %}checked{% endif %} onclick="submit();"> 
  {% endfor %}
```

[Here is an example of what the switch looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoTqs.png)

**In the flask app.py** I have a list of devices and when a POST request is sent, it loops through the devices list to check which autopilot to turn on or off.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():  
    global devices
    if request.method == "POST":
        # decode response & filter out the unique ID
        response = request.get_data().decode("utf-8")
        resp_device_id = response.split(".")[0]
        
        # compare unique ID with devices & toggle autopilot
        for d in devices:
            if str(d.unique_id) == resp_device_id:
                d.autopilot = not d.autopilot
            else:
                print(str(d.unique_id) + "&" + resp_device_id + "do not match")
    return render_template('home.html', devices = devices)
```

Everything works when switching from OFF to ON. But the POST response seems empty when switching from ON to OFF. And so the IF statement results in FALSE and nothing gets switched.

Any ideas what could go wrong here?

Comment: Do you use Javascript? Did you check if you don't get error in JavaScript console? Maybe it raise error and later it doesn't stop reloading it.

Comment: what value do you expected when it is unchecked? As I remeber when input is unchecked then it doesn't send value and this way you can recognize that it is unchecked. So in view first you should set all values on `False` and later code will set `True` for all checkboxes which you got from browser.

Comment: Thanks @furas your comment lead me to the answer. No value gets send when unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out eventually.
Appearantly this is the expected behavior.

The page doesn't send the data if the box is unchecked. So the response is actually empty.
To identify the switch, I added a hidden field to the form.
Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="{{device.unique_id}}" name="device" value="{{device.unique_id}}">
```